# UrlRewriteFilter outbound to add host/subdomains to static resource paths

Tags: java, url-rewriting, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I need to have a filter to add subdomain paths to image and static paths from a java application.

Eg: `/foo/bar/xyz.jpg` would become `http://img1.foobar.com/foo/bar/xyz.jpg`, where the protocol should correspond to the request's protocol, and the `img1` is derived from an existing piece of code we already use to map resources to subdomains.

This has come about because we place static content on cookieless domains for content in our web-templates, but sometimes HTML is pulled in from our CMS which is maintained by a 3rd party that will just have relative URLs in the HTML.

I have looked at http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ but it seems like an overkill for what we need. Plus, I wasn't able to see whether you could append URLs in an outbound rule (rather than just issue a redirect - I dont want redirects, but a replacement feature on the outbound HTML). I also need to be able to dynamically generate the `img1` based on our existing code, and I'm not sure this is possible with UrlRewriteFilter. I have also seen this http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=106 but it is yet to be implemented.

Does anyone have any suggestions here?